# How read feather file with duplicative columns in R

Tags: r, feather

I have a problem with reading data files in feather format which has 2+ columns with duplicative names. Is it possible to drop duplicative names on meta data level or load data with duplicative names in some way.

Let say data set "mtcars" is saved on disk and by

```
feather_metadata("mtcars")
```

gives

[32 x 12] @ mtcars

- 'mpg'  : double
- 'mpg'  : double
- 'mpg'  : double
- 'cyl'  : double
- 'disp' : double

By using `"read_feather("mtcars")` it generates error

Error: Column names `mpg`, `mpg`, must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.

How fix this problem?

Comment: install.packages('feather'), perhaps? I haven't been challenged by the format, but [feather](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found - read data by column indexes:

```
read_feather("mtcars", columns = c(1, 4, 5)
```

This allows to pass duplicative columns.